# Is there a formula for the Butcher tableau for the implicit Runge Kutta method for an arbitrary number of stages?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

Usually the Runge Kutta method uses 4 stages. What if I want to use an arbitrary number of stages like 300 stages, which is possible in some domains (e.g. with physics informed neural networks). Is there a general formula for the necessary constants?

I.e., I'm seeking sets of $c_i$, $b_i$, and $a_{ij}$ as described in the implicit RK section at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods .

Answer (score 2):

Gauß methods with $s$ stages have order 2s, Radau IIa methods have order 2s-1.

The order declines as one adds additional conditions. For instance that $A$ be lower triangular with the same number in every diagonal entry ((special) diagonally implicit RK methods).

For a more detailed overview see the slides PDFs in [https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebutcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/)

---

While one can take 75 steps of RK4 and call it a 300 stage method, it will still have order 4. Using Richardson extrapolation like Burlisch-Stoer will increase the order, but is far from opimal. The order conditions for RK methods are polynomials of increasing degrees, making a general solution complicated to hopeless. With structured additional conditions methods in the order range 12-20 have been constructed. There do not exist real viable use cases for such high-order methods, cf. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25581/why-are-higher-order-runge-kutta-methods-not-used-more-often

Comment: It seems that they are actually doing high order RK methods, with butcher tableaus in the 4 megabyte range. https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs/blob/master/main/discrete_time_identification%20(KdV)/KdV.py
https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs/tree/master/Utilities/IRK_weights

Comment: I'm not sure what they do there with the IRK data, it does not look like an implicit Runge-Kutta method, more like a very complicated first-order step. As said, Gauß methods and other collocation methods can be formulated for any order. But for a fixed order and a fixed floating-point configuation the range of useful step sizes reduces to nothing with increasing order. Or said otherwise, to meaningfully employ high-order method, one needs to compute with multi-precision numbers with a high enough precision. But then the IRK coeffs need also be that accurate.